# Get rid of vertical line when using Show with ListLinePlot

Tags: plotting

I have two list line plots and in the end I want to combine them with the Show command. This works, however only up to an annoying vertical line in the plot. I don't know how to get rif of that line. It seems to be a specific feature of ListLinePlot, since if I do the same with the normal Plot command the vertical line does not appear.
Here is the code:

```
t1 = {{1/5000, 1.04}, {1/2500, 2.0}, {3/5000, 3.0447}};

t2 = {{-(1/5000), 1.04}, {-(1/2500), 2.0}, {-(3/5000), 3.0447}};

pl1 = ListLinePlot[t1, PlotStyle -> Blue, PlotRange -> All, 
  Frame -> {True, True, True, True}, Axes -> True, 
  FrameTicks -> {Automatic, {{{-(3/5000), 
       "-6\[Times]\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(-4\)]\)"}, {-(1/
        5000), "-2\[Times]\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(-4\)]\)"}, \
{1/5000, "2\[Times]\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(-4\)]\)"}, {3/5000, 
       "6\[Times]\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(-4\)]\)"}}, None}}, 
  FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[13], 
  FrameLabel -> {Style["x", 13], Style["\[Beta]", 15]}]
pl2 = ListLinePlot[t2, PlotStyle -> Green, PlotRange -> All, 
  Frame -> {True, True, True, True}, Axes -> True, 
  FrameTicks -> {Automatic, {{{-(3/5000), 
       "-6\[Times]\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(-4\)]\)"}, {-(1/
        5000), "-2\[Times]\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(-4\)]\)"}, \
{1/5000, "2\[Times]\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(-4\)]\)"}, {3/5000, 
       "6\[Times]\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(-4\)]\)"}}, None}}, 
  FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[13], 
  FrameLabel -> {Style["x", 13], Style["\[Beta]", 15]}]
Show[pl1, pl2, PlotRange -> All]
```

And here is the result that I get:

[image]

Comment: What if you add `Axes -> None` to `Show[]`?

Comment: It works!!! Thank you so much! You can write an answer and upvote it

Comment: That being said, notice that you added `Axes -> True` to both `pl2` and `pl1`. ;) You should have used `Axes -> None` in there to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
t1 = {{1/5000, 1.04}, {1/2500, 2.0}, {3/5000, 3.0447}};

t2 = {{-(1/5000), 1.04}, {-(1/2500), 2.0}, {-(3/5000), 3.0447}};
```

You can save a lot of code by using a single [`ListLinePlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListLinePlot.html)

```
ListLinePlot[{
  Callout[t1, "t1", Below],
  Callout[t2, "t2", Below]},
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, Green},
 Frame -> True,
 Axes -> False,
 FrameTicks -> {Automatic, {{
     {-(3/5000), "-6×\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(-4\)]\)"},
     {-(1/5000), "-2×\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(-4\)]\)"},
     {1/5000, "2×\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(-4\)]\)"},
     {3/5000, "6×\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(-4\)]\)"}}, None}},
 FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[13],
 FrameLabel -> {Style["x", 13], Style["β", 15]}]
```

[image]